# evaluate formula in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a formula and an object containing variables as a key
My object is as

```
{
 xyz:{
     v:20
  },
 ab:{
     v:2
  },
 y:{
     v:30
  },
 z:{
     v:40
  },

}
```

Now I have to evaluate the formula

Eg.

```
xyz+ab*(y+z)
```

> Result : 20+2*(30+40)

Any optimized solution ?

> > Please note that keys are in the form of "characters..characters" 
> >     eg. `ABC..XY12`
> >
> > Update : Actual object is

```
{
 pnl..xyz:{
     v:20
  },
 pxl..ab:{
     v:2
  },
 pnl..y:{
     v:30
  },
 pxl..z:{
     v:40
  },

}
```

and the formula is

```
pnl..xyz+pxl..ab*(pnl..y+pxl..z)
```

Comment: why do you need regex?

Comment: oK  will any optimized solution.

Comment: Is `xyz+ab*(y+z)` a string that is given as input? Or can it be something like `obj.xyz+obj.ab...`?

Comment: The formula looks perfect, why is this a problem?

Comment: yes xyz+ab*(y+z) is a string.

Comment: I need to replace the variables with the values

Comment: This should work for you: obj.xyz.v + obj.ab.v * (obj.y.v + obj.z.v)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex to find variable names and post that you can use `eval`

#### Sample

```js
var data={xyz:{v:20},ab:{v:2},y:{v:30},z:{v:40},abc12:{v:12},"abc..bc":{v:31}};

function processOperation(str) {
  var formula = str;
  var operatios = /[+\-\*\/\(\)]/g;
  var keys = formula.split(operatios);
  keys.forEach(function(k) {
    if (k && data[k]) formula = formula.replace(k, data[k].v)
  });
  console.log(formula);
  return eval(formula)
}

var formula1 = "xyz+ab*(y+z)"
console.log(processOperation(formula1))

var formula2 = "xyz+ab*(y+z)-abc12"
console.log(processOperation(formula2))

var formula3 = "xyz+ab*(y+z)-12"
console.log(processOperation(formula3))

var formula4 = "xyz+ab*(y+z)-abc..bc"
console.log(processOperation(formula4))
```

Comment: Thats interesting

Comment: you can do it in one line with `replace` and replacement function

Comment: Thanks for the answer, My keys are in the form of "abcd..ab12" .

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own custom parser and evaluator, but there will be loads of edge cases, validation and operator precedence cases to be
taken care of.
I would recommend not reinventing the wheel, and using [math.js](http://mathjs.org/download.html) , it is a lightweight dedicated library for maths in javascript.
Here is how formula evaluation can be done in a single line.

```js
var scope = { xyz : 20,  ab : 2, y : 30, z : 40 };
var answer = math.eval('xyz+ab*(y+z)', scope); 
console.log('The answer is:' + answer);
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/3.5.3/math.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This function will replace the keys of the provided `obj` in the provided `formula` string. It's curried so you can reuse the same formula with different values for the variables.

```js
const obj = {
 xyz:{ v:20 },
 ab:{ v:2 },
 y:{ v:30 },
 z:{ v:40 }
}

const obj2 = {
 'pnl..xyz':{ v:20 },
 'pxl..ab':{ v:2 },
 'pnl..y':{ v:30 },
 'pxl..z':{ v:40 },
}

 /*
 * evalFormula :: String -> {key:{v:Int}} -> String
 *
 * replace the formula string with the obj values
*/
const evalFormula = formula => obj => {
  // get the keys
  const keys = Object.keys(obj)
  // sort keys by length so we replace the longer strings first
  keys.sort(sortBy('length'))
  // reduce the keys into the formula
  return keys.reduce((str, key) => 
    // replace the key with it's corresponding value each iteration
    str.replace(stringToRegex(key, 'g'), obj[key].v)
  , formula)
}

// get a regular expression from an input string
const stringToRegex = (str, modifiers) => 
  new RegExp(str.replace(/([\.\^\$\*\+\-\?\(\)\[\]\{\}\\])/g, '\$1'), modifiers)

const sortBy = prop => (a, b) => a[prop] > b[prop] ? -1 : a[prop] < b[prop] ? 1 : 0

// this is the executable function
const execFormula = evalFormula('xyz+ab*(y+z)')
const otherFormula = evalFormula('pnl..xyz+pxl..ab*(pnl..y+pxl..z)')

console.log(
  execFormula(obj),
  otherFormula(obj2)
)
```

Edit.

You would just need to add in a little escaping for the illegal characters in your keys, then create a new formula and pass in the new obj

Comment: Can you please explain in a little more detail.

Comment: @Vishu238 the code is updated to handle the new obj and formula